# How to clear the detection using on-screen buttons?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

[image]

Basically, I want to be able to clear the augmentation using the **X button**  on the top-left corner of the screen, as shown in the picture.

This was done using some script in Unity3D.
Any idea how this is done?

Here's the link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9tksyhVlIMQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are my findings:

- If you want on-screen buttons, then just parent the button UI to the Camera and position in a particular corner of the screen or something.
- Now if you function it to work like if pressed and you want to clear or start detection use these:

  ```
  TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ImageTracker>().Stop();
  TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ImageTracker>().Start();
  ```

Took me a long time to figure this out. Hope it helps someone out there. :)